# Java JFace TableViewer fix/freeze row

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

I've build an application in Java with the help of JFace/SWT. I am using mainly the `TableViewer` of JFace and sometime the SWT table behind with `myTableViewer.getTable()`.

My table has a header (filled with the column names) and the first row is rendered with `CCombos` in `CellEditors` (drop down menus for filters).

Now I want to fix this first row ("filter-row") in the table, so it is always shown, independently if I am scrolling down or not..

Do you know any opportunity to do this (instead of splitting one table in two tables, as I found it in the internet)?

Answer (score 0):

The SWT Table does not support fixed rows or columns.

If the combos were inteded to hold a limited number of choices you may use [context menus on the column headers](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet311.java) instead.

There are also alternative Table-like implementations in varying degrees of maturity that you may consider:

- [Nebula Grid](https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php)
- [XViewer](https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/xviewer/xviewer.php)
- [NatTable](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/)

If non of the above fits your requirements you will have to either use a distinct table that holds the combo widgets or implement a custom 'header' control.